# Java Three D Array in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

m1 method has 3-d array as argument, also printing b (object reference) gives `[[[I@15db9742` which implies that a is 3-d array but in for loop (bold) a is behaving as 2-d array, if i write it as int x[][][]:a then it is

```
giving error " Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type int[][] to 
     int[][][]"
```

**What is the reason of this behavior ?**

```
public class Arr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][][] aa2=new int[2][1][];

        m1(aa2);
    }

    public static void m1(int[][][] b)
    {
        **for(int[][] x:b)**
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Comment: A 3D array is effectively an array of 2D arrays.  Thus when you want to iterate over one, that is what you will get.

Comment: At which line do you have the error

Comment: If you want to print the 2D array used in the loop, just change the output to `System.out.println(x)`.

Comment: But **if** he only tried to print it, there's no reason to have his error, so that's probably a typo.

Comment: @Nathan in for loop in bold

Comment: @Nathan if I declare int[] [] [] X : b in for loop

Comment: That makes no sense. If `b` was a `int[]`, do you think `for (int[] X : b)` would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You for-loop is not correct. What you are doing is iteration over the array `b` which is `int[][][]` (you called it the 3D-Array) to get the next lower layer `int[][]`.

But then you used `System.out.println(b);` which is not printing out your `int[][]` but the `int[][][]` that was passed to your method, basicly the for-loop is never used.

This would do the job:

```
public static void m1(int[][][] b)
{
    for(int[][] x : b)
       System.out.println(x);

}
```

Result:

> [[I@15db9742
>   [[I@6d06d69c

Comment: thanks for the answer but my issue is that b is a 3 D array but in for loop I have to declare X as 2 D array if i declare X as 3 D array then it is giving error, 
Please ignore system.out.println

Comment: @bharatbhushan of course it's giving you an error then. You're iterating over an Array of an Array of an array of ints (3d Array) so what you get in a for loop is an Array of an array of ints (2d Array)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "3D array" in Java. It is a [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) to former C/C++ programmers, it looks the same but it is something completely different.

An array in Java is always 2D. It does not even have the "dimensions", actually each "row" can contain different number of "columns".

Please study the [Oracle tutorial on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Your array in fact might look like this:

- yellow: first "dimension", contains **references** to `int[][]`
- blue: second "dimension", contains **references** to `int[]`
- green: third "dimension", contains directly the `int` numbers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) syntax.

You do not have to re-declare the array-variable itself, but instead explicitly declare the type of elements you are expecting from the iteration.

```
int[] array;
for (      String             element       :     array)
//     element type  ||  element variable  ||  array variable
```

Note the `String[]` vs `String`.

- `String[] array` declares the array variable you are iterating over.
- `String element` declares the element type you are expecting. You can also declare `Object element`, as `String` is a subclass of `Object`.

---

Now, as already elaborated in other questions, a '3-d array' does not actually exist in java, but it is merely an array of arrays of arrays - or in other words an array of '2-d arrays'.

This is why the following syntax is required in the example you provided:

```
int[][][] array;
for (int[][] element : array)
```